# Passing dynamic arguments to gman_do mysql udf function

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, gearman

I am trying to use gearman's mysql udf functions (version 0.6) .

When i call it like this :

```
select gman_do_background("test", "_", "_");
```

or even

```
select gman_do_background(CONCAT("te","st"), "_", "_");
```

It works, and my worker "test" procedure is triggered.

But if i try to do  :

```
CREATE DEFINER  PROCEDURE `CallGearmanBackground`(IN `jobtocall` VARCHAR(70))
     BEGIN select gman_do_background(jobtocall, "_", "_" );
END
```

and then

```
call CallGearmanBackground("test");
```

I get this error :

> Can't initialize function 'gman_do_background'; First argument must be
>   a string.

I tried several type for the procedure argument (VARBINARY, TEXT, BLOB ) ... all trigger the same error.

Any way around this ?